# Adding dynamically a Textbox with jQuery Mobile style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, textbox

I will dynamically add some textbox to my page. 
It works perfectly, but i get the standart html textbox.
I want a textbox in jquery style.

```
output += "<li><table><form id='elementForm'><tbody>";
output += "<tr><td><label>" + metaLabel[j] + " </label></td>";
output += "<td><input type='text' name='text-1' id='text-1' value=" + ajaxDataRecordSet.recordset[clicked][testVar] + "></td></tr>"
output += "</tbody></form></table></li>";
$(output).appendTo("#content1");
$('#content1').listview('refresh');
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: I'm using jquery mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `listview` I assume you mean jQuery Mobile? You need to also call `textinput()` on any input text fields to refresh them:

```
$("#content1 :text").textinput();
```

As the [documentation for textinput](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/textinputs/) states:

> This plugin will auto initialize on any page that contains a textarea
>   or any of the text input types listed above without any need for a
>   data-role attribute in the markup. However, if needed, you can
>   directly call the textinput plugin on any selector, just like any
>   jQuery plugin

Comment: If it doesn't already exist, you can call `.trigger("create")` on all newly created elements as per Vinod's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `$('#elementID').trigger("create")` to make it work.

Comment: Triggering the `create` method *initializes* the listview. At this stage the listview has already been initialized, so he needs to call `refresh`.